# Write each row in feature layer to an individual text file in Python

Tags: python, arcpy

Featurelayer contains multiple columns, but I am only interested in FieldB and FieldT.

```
FieldB
1
2
3

FieldT
Text1
Text2
```

In my C:\Temp, I want to have:
file1.txt and content inside will show "Text1"

```
C:\Temp\file2.txt
Text2

C:\Temp\file3.txt
Text3
```

My current code looks like this:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Temp\\"
featurelayer="C:\\Temp\\Mylayer"
content = "FieldT"
filename = "FieldB"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(featurelayer, filename) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        coFile = "file" + str(row[0]) + ".txt"

    with open(os.path.join("C:\\Temp\\textfiles", coFile), 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n\n'.join(r.FieldT for r in arcpy.SearchCursor(featurelayer)))
```

I know I need a iterator somewhere, but I am having trouble where to place it.

Currently this code will create the files with filenames using FieldB. But the content inside each of the text files contains all content for every row under FieldT.

Comment: This is more basic Python flow-of-control than GIS.  Your first `with` block doesn't do anything useful (as a `with`), and your third `with` should be inside the second (which will eliminate the invalid and deprecated `arcpy.SearchCursor`).  Right now `coFile` is defined according to the last row before it is used.

Comment: Now the indentation is wrong (won't run) and the flow of control is still wrong. Note that thanks and signatures are inappropriate in GIS SE -- Please don't add them again

Comment: sorry about that, new to the site. my code has the correct idents and the code runs. Just having all content for every single textfile when i just want individual content per filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following is something like what you're looking for...changed the double back slashes to forward slashes (yes, still works in Windows), and some of the variable names for more clarity...

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Temp/"
featurelayer="C:/Temp/Mylayer"
contentField = "FieldT"
filenameField = "FieldB"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(featurelayer, [filenameField, contentField]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        coFile = "file" + str(row[0]) + ".txt"
        with open(os.path.join("C:/Temp/textfiles", coFile), 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(row[1]))
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks Jason! I was messing up doing a singular field per SearchCursor!